# Using Perl to Extract Multiple Iterms from Text

Tags: perl

I need to extract multiple items from a multi-line string.

```
{
      'autoname' => 1,
      'class' => 'packetfilter',
      'data' => {
                  'action' => 'accept',
                  'auto' => 0,
                  'auto_type' => '',
                  'comment' => 'Allow access to Sandbox Server',
                  'destinations' => [
                                      'REF_NetworkAny'
                                    ],
                  'direction' => '',
                  'group' => 'SANDBOX',
                  'interface' => '',
                  'log' => 1,
                  'name' => 'TCP_5090 from SND (Network) to Any',
                  'services' => [
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp5090',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp8200',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp8883',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcpudp5090'
                                ],
                  'source_mac_addresses' => '',
                  'sources' => [
                                 'REF_MHTGIvpkvI'
                               ],
                  'status' => 1,
                  'time' => ''
                },
      'hidden' => 0,
      'lock' => '',
      'nodel' => '',
      'ref' => 'REF_PacPacTcp50FromSnd',
      'type' => 'packetfilter'
    }
```

I need to locate the tags 'services', destinations and sources and extract only the REF tags for each.

Example:

```
services
REF_SerTcpTcp5090
REF_SerTcpTcp8200
REF_SerTcpTcp8883
REF_SerTcpTcpudp5090

destinations
REF_NetworkAny

sources
REF_MHTGIvpkvI
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your string looks like a hash definition in Perl source code. Where did the string come from? If it is within the source code you can simply use Perl syntax to access a nested hash

Answer (score 2):

That sure looks like Perl.  You could use `eval` to turn it into a Perl data structure, but that has numerous security problems.

Instead, use [the Safe module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe#permit_only-OP) to eval it, but allowing only certain operators. This will block it from doing *some* insecure things like opening files or adding functions.  Here's a demonstration.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Safe;

my $safe = Safe->new;
my $data = $safe->reval(join "", <DATA>) or die "reval failed: $@";
say join "\n", keys %$data;

__END__
{
      'autoname' => 1,
      'class' => 'packetfilter',
      'data' => {
                  'action' => 'accept',
                  'auto' => 0,
                  'auto_type' => '',
                  'comment' => 'Allow access to Sandbox Server',
                  'destinations' => [
                                      'REF_NetworkAny'
                                    ],
                  'direction' => '',
                  'group' => 'SANDBOX',
                  'interface' => '',
                  'log' => 1,
                  'name' => 'TCP_5090 from SND (Network) to Any',
                  'services' => [
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp5090',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp8200',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp8883',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcpudp5090'
                                ],
                  'source_mac_addresses' => '',
                  'sources' => [
                                 'REF_MHTGIvpkvI'
                               ],
                  'status' => 1,
                  'time' => ''
                },
      'hidden' => 0,
      'lock' => '',
      'nodel' => '',
      'ref' => 'REF_PacPacTcp50FromSnd',
      'type' => 'packetfilter'
}
```

Safe is not 100% safe, so you shouldn't make this a habit. If at all possible, use a parsable format such as JSON for your data serialization.

Answer (score 1):

If your input data set is valid Perl code the easiest way should be evaluating the code using `eval` as suggested by the other answers. As already mention there are some security issues if the you do not trust the source of your input data. So use it carefully and think about the usage of a module to further shrink the attack surface. 
Another solution could be usage of regular expressions. Assuming that you have the complete input data in a scalar you can parse for your required items

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = join "", <DATA>;

my @services = get_values(\$data, 'services');
my @destinations = get_values(\$data, 'destinations');
my @sources = get_values(\$data, 'sources');

print "Services: ", join(", ", @services),"\n";
print "Destinations: ", join(", ", @destinations),"\n";
print "Sources: ", join(", ", @sources),"\n";

sub get_values
{
    my ($inputdata, $key) = @_;

    # add quote signs around the key
    $key = "'$key'";

    if ($$inputdata =~ /$key => \[([^\]]+)\]/m)
    {
    # $1 contains the values
    my $values = $1;
    # remove empty lines, plus leading and tailing whitespaces
    $values =~ s/^\s*$|^\s+|\s+$//mg;
    # strip line breaks and single quotes
    $values =~ s/[\n']//g;
    # split into seperate fields
    my @result = split(/,/, $values);

    return @result;
    } else {
    return ();
    }
}

__END__
{
      'autoname' => 1,
      'class' => 'packetfilter',
      'data' => {
                  'action' => 'accept',
                  'auto' => 0,
                  'auto_type' => '',
                  'comment' => 'Allow access to Sandbox Server',
                  'destinations' => [
                                      'REF_NetworkAny'
                                    ],
                  'direction' => '',
                  'group' => 'SANDBOX',
                  'interface' => '',
                  'log' => 1,
                  'name' => 'TCP_5090 from SND (Network) to Any',
                  'services' => [
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp5090',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp8200',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcp8883',
                                  'REF_SerTcpTcpudp5090'
                                ],
                  'source_mac_addresses' => '',
                  'sources' => [
                                 'REF_MHTGIvpkvI'
                               ],
                  'status' => 1,
                  'time' => ''
                },
      'hidden' => 0,
      'lock' => '',
      'nodel' => '',
      'ref' => 'REF_PacPacTcp50FromSnd',
      'type' => 'packetfilter'
}
```

The advantage of the regular expression approach are no (or at least reduced) security issues with untrusted data sources.

Frank

EDIT: Added example code.

Answer (score -1):

As one of the commenters already noted - the data is valid perl - possibly created by Data::Dumper or something similar.  To get the data back, simply eval it:

```
use v5.12;
use Path::Tiny "path";                            # Used for slurp

my $data_string = path("mit.txt")->slurp_utf8;    # random filename for data
my $data = eval $data_string ;
warn $@ if $@;
say "Servies:\n  ",       join(", ", @{  $data->{ data }->{services}      });
say "Destinations:\n  ",  join(", ", @{  $data->{ data }->{destinations}  });
say "Sources:\n  ",       join(", ", @{  $data->{ data }->{sources}       });
exit 0;
#
# Outputs:
#
Servies:
  REF_SerTcpTcp5090, REF_SerTcpTcp8200, REF_SerTcpTcp8883, REF_SerTcpTcpudp5090
Destinations:
  REF_NetworkAny
Sources:
  REF_MHTGIvpkvI
```

Note this warning from [Data::Dumper documnetation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html);

*Given a list of scalars or reference variables, writes out their contents in perl syntax. The references can also be objects. The content of each variable is output in a single Perl statement. Handles self-referential structures correctly.*

*The return value can be evaled to get back an identical copy of the original reference structure. **(Please do consider the security implications of eval'ing code from untrusted sources!)***

Comment: I downvoted because there's no discussion of the security implications of eval'ing a data file.

Comment: Give the umpire a chance to blow the whistle. :-)  I was adding it while you were commenting - ie not in response to your comment.

Comment: Downvote remains since no solution is offered by the answer or that blithe comment in Data::Dumper. Sorry, eval'ing data files is a bad practice even if you warn the person it's a bad practice.

Comment: Fair enough - hadn't heard of Safe.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: That's ok, neither has Data::Dumper. :-/